# How to see the last filled value in a row?

Tags: r

I'm new to R. Here I got a little trouble in my task when I attempted to find the last filled value in a row. Let's say, I have a table which is like:

```
Name   D1   D2   D3   D4   D5
-----+----+----+----+----+----
Stacy  1    4    NA   6    NA
Joy    NA   4    8    NA   8
Anna   NA   NA   7    1    NA
Ray    2    NA   3    NA   NA
Fey    8    NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Based on the data, I want to extract the last filled value from each row. Where the expected table I attempted to build was like

```
Name   D1   D2   D3   D4   D5   LastD
-----+----+----+----+----+----+-------
Stacy  1    4    NA   6    NA   6
Joy    NA   4    8    NA   8    8
Anna   NA   NA   7    1    NA   1
Ray    2    NA   3    NA   NA   2
Fey    8    NA   NA   NA   NA   8
```

Or just a single column of "LastD" is okay. So far, this is the code I write.

```
data2 <- for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
    x <- rep(0, nrow(data))
    for (j in ncol(data):1) {
        if (!is.na(data[i,j])) {
        x[i] <- data[i,j]
            }
        }
    return(x)
    }
```

I know it was a very simple code and I also realize that it had its flaws here and there. Could you help me to improve it?

Comment: One way to do it, `apply(df, 1, function(i) tail(i[!is.na(i)], 1))`

Comment: my answer is almost identical :P I should have refreshed before posting

Comment: no problem. I hate doing `apply` with margin 1 anyway. Maybe I ll post a more vectorized solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
df <- read.table(text = '
   D1   D2   D3   D4   D5
Stacy  1    4    NA   6    NA
Joy    NA   4    8    NA   8
Anna   NA   NA   7    1    NA
Ray    2    NA   3    NA   NA
Fey    8    NA   NA   NA   NA',
       header = TRUE)

df$D6 <- apply(df, 1, function(x) tail(x[!is.na(x)], 1))

df

      D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6
Stacy  1  4 NA  6 NA  6
Joy   NA  4  8 NA  8  8
Anna  NA NA  7  1 NA  1
Ray    2 NA  3 NA NA  3
Fey    8 NA NA NA NA  8
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `row/column` to extract the values

```
df$D6 <- df[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), max.col(!is.na(df), "last"))]
df$D6
#[1] 6 8 1 3 8
```